# Select min, max for all match from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my [Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e09fb)

I have two tables Client and PIPOOrder.

It should show all the entries of minimum and maximum matched for alpha and beta (and all users)

```
Client  | Order
alpha   |alpha  01/01/2004
beta    |alpha  02/02/2004
alpha1  |alpha  05/05/2014
Test    |beta   05/05/2014
test1   |beta   01/05/2014


select min(created_at) as FirstOrder,max(created_at) as LatestOrder from pipo_orders
```

Here is what i tried so far, What is the mistake i am doing, and how can i do this ?

### Update :

**I need to do that in Left Join**

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.clientname,
       min(created_at) as FirstOrder,
       max(created_at) as LatestOrder 
from client c
left join pipo_orders p on c.clientid = p.clientid
group by c.clientid, c.clientname
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e09fb/6)

Comment: I have different query at here http://paste.ofcode.org/ksE9z6tRzKiSKSb8t22Whm i tried to join your query at the last part, buti face error. How can i do that

Answer (score 0):

use GROUP BY like so:

```
select Client, min(created_at) as FirstOrder,max(created_at) as LatestOrder from pipo_orders group by Client
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking, I looked at you  [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e09fb).
Hope below is what you looking for:

```
select ClientName,pipo1.FirstOrder,pipo2.LastOrder
from client as c1 inner join
    (select ClientID,min(created_at) as FirstOrder from pipo_orders group by ClientID) 
    as pipo1 on c1.ClientID = pipo1.ClientID inner join 
    (select ClientID,max(created_at) as LastOrder from pipo_orders group by ClientID)
    as pipo2 on c1.ClientID = pipo2.ClientID
```

Comment: I have different query at here http://paste.ofcode.org/ksE9z6tRzKiSKSb8t22Whm i tried to join your query at the last part, buti face error. How can i do that

Comment: Try to remove the group by from the main query and paste inside the subquery and remove the alias cl.